# Is it ok to call self overloaded initializer?

Tags: objective-c

In below overloaded initializers is it OK to call [self initWith..]? since i am calling something on 'self' when [super init] is yet to happen?

When i tested this all works good. Does that mean one can call method on 'self' even before [super init] call? Can anyone help me understand this?

```
-(id)initWithObjectA:(id)objectA{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //Do other initializations
        //Use ObjectA
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithObjectA:(id)objectA andWithObjectB:(id)objectB{

    if (self = [self initWithObjectA:objectA]) {
        //Use ObjectB
    }
    return self;
}

//More overloading initializers
```

Thanks.

Comment: In Objective-C methods can't be overloaded (have two definitions with different types). These are different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html), the designated initializer for a given class should perform all actual initialization; the other initializers should directly or indirectly call the designated initializer. So you're right in thinking that one initializer should call the other, but the example you provided is doing it backwards. Consider rewriting the methods as follows:

```
- (id)initWithObjectA:(id)objectA
{
    return [self initWithObjectA:objectA objectB:nil];
}

- (id)initWithObjectA:(id)objectA objectB:(id)objectB
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // Perform custom initialization...
    }

    return self;
}
```

**EDIT**

With regard to sending a message to `self` before an object has been fully initialized, of course that's okay. If you think about it, `self` is a pointer that's initialized when an object receives a message. (`self` is actually passed into the method as a hidden argument, but that's another story.) Given that the object in question has already received a message, there's no reason it shouldn't be able to send itself additional messages.

Comment: +1 I should add that the self pointer is set on alloc, which is the reason why you can send any message to self in the initializer.

Comment: And it appears, method call right after alloc also working. Below code also works without any exceptions: Overloaded *ol1 = [Overloaded alloc]; NSLog(@"%@",[ol1 saythis]); And thanks for pointing me that i did it in reverse.

Comment: @Galaxy You're welcome. By the way, as others have pointed out, you seem to be mixing up the term *overloading* with the term *overriding*. Objective-C doesn't support overloading, and your question concerns overriding inherited methods, rather than overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works fine. I often do this to initialize private variables with defauls values. This helps you write less code and shows the constructors hierarchy.

`self` here works the same way as you write `super`. So it just calls other constructor.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this. this is like simple methods calling from some othe methods. nothing bad here. according to your number of objects you can call your perticular initializer.

its'not a just ok , it is the best way always